# how can i override z-index of drop-down auto complete over background image?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

How can I set `z-index` of the drop-down autocomplete box over a background image?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Below four images are background images with sprite CSS and the area box is drop-down autocomplete and it has `position` set to `absolute` and `z-index` set to `100`, but still it's not overlapping background image.

Here is the CSS for the drop-down box and the bottom section.

**Drop Down Box:**

```
.tt-dropdown-menu,
.tt-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 79%!important;
  left: 9px!important;
  z-index: 1000;
  min-width: 160px;
  width: 94%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 0px!important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

**Below Section:**

```
.hero-banner {
  color: #555;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #EFEDEB;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
}
```

**Sprite CSS:**

```
.why_casebox {
  background-image: url(../images/why-casebox/why_casebox.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.sprite-verified {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background-position: -143px -143px;
}
```

Even though the title and description text are also overriding.

Answer (score 1):

```
.hero-banner {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

or

I don't know whether it is position above for whole div or for the third child with icon.

```
.why_casebox {
     z-index: 0;
}
```

so that image will position behind the dropdown.

Comment: both sections are different.

one section is having blue background and another section have 4 images

Comment: check the image file u attached heading title is behind the dropdown box in the  banner section. so, the  image is above the dropdown with higher z-index value.

Comment: i have also tried to decrease z-index of image, but when i am starting to apply z-index in minus it hides my image.

Comment: In the image section, header is hidden behind by the dropdown, but the image and the text are above the dropdown. so just try to z-index '0' for this section (.sprite-verified or .why_casebox  or parent class for both). But i can't get any idea without the html.

Comment: if u set z-index in minus vaue it will hide behind the body.